# What card face value cardinality patterns can always be shared by all 4 players with 13 cards each?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, card-games

In a hand of 13 cards from a standard 52 card deck there will always be a certain number of singles, double, triples and quadruples. For example, I might have 6 singles, 2 doubles and a triple (for 13 cards in total) denoted by $a^6b^2c$, by which I mean that for precisely 1 face value (perhaps "King") I have 3 different cards, for precisely 2 more (perhaps "Jack" and "Eight") I have 2 different cards and for another 6 face values I have precisely one card. (My calculations suggest this is in fact the most likely combination, see the SageMath notebook [here](https://github.com/yclicc/QuantumPresident/blob/main/QuantumPresident.ipynb)).

Now envisage a game of four-player [President](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/presidents/) in which instead of playing the cards from a randomly selected hand, players pick up cards from the complete deck laid out on the table until they have a 13 card hand. Clearly, if we allow players to pick up any 13 cards the first player will always win (by first picking up 4 aces, then 4 kings, 4 queens and then 1 jack, at each point an unbeatable choice). Therefore, we must make an additional constraint on the hand that must be collected by specifying the cardinality pattern.

The problem is, for some cardinality patterns it is impossible for all four players to collect them at the same time, whilst for others it is possible but not guaranteed for all players to be able to collect them.

For example, when I tried the game with the constraint above ($a^6b^2c$) I arrived at

```
P1: QQQ9977K86542
P2: AAAJJ446532 left 32
P3: 000JJ99865432
P4: KKK8877AQ0653
```

as the hand of each player, player 2 being unable to finish. However, it is in theory possible for all players to finish with this rule:

```
P1: AAA0088J65432
P2: KKK0088A65432
P3: QQQ9977K65432
P4: JJJ9977Q65432
```

Clearly the trivial constraint $a^{13}$ (13 singles each) guarantees that all players will always be able to finish simultaneously, but this will give quite a boring game. <strike>This can be modified to $a^{10}c$ without issue because any face value for which one player takes a triple will have precisely a single remaining (the final split will be xxx|x||) thus reducing the problem to $a^9$ with 9 face values remaining once all players have taken precisely one triple and one single.</strike> (Edit: Not always winnable. See comments). However, doubles (which can split the four cards of a face value between the players either xx|x|x| or xx|xx||) create a lot of unpredictability.

**Which other face value cardinalities are guaranteed to allow all 4 players to always finish successfully? Which among these allows for the most possible permutations of hands?**

Comment: Could you include some discussion on why $a^{10}c$ can always be done, no matter whether three players conspire to make it impossible for the fourth to finish?

Comment: Yep, done. My suspicion is that in fact any number of triples and singles will work, and that the introduction of doubles always breaks things but I'm not sure of this.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion of $a^{10}c.$ If your suspicion ot the lastr comment were proved, would not that complete the enumeration of all cases which would always work?

Comment: Yes, it would, but I'm not clear how it could be proved. Furthermore, there are some with only triples and singles which don't work, such as $ac^4$, since then there are more triples than singles (and every triple chosen "forces" a corresponding single namely the single card that remains).

Comment: Oh wait, $a^{10}c$ doesn't work always. Suppose all four players take a single from the first 10 face values, then for each of the 3 remaining face values the first second and third player takes a triple. This leaves the 4th player with one card left of each of those face values, meaning they can only manage $a^{13}$.

Comment: tex... I think you're right. (will check it more thoroughly later...) Then it might be only $a^{13}$ can guarantee it.